# How do you apply predicates in XSLT stylesheet so mulitiple rows in a table showing same level elements are filtered by predicate

Tags: xml, xslt, dom

I am applying xpath expression(s) into an XSLT stylesheet mainly in the
for each and value-of sections of anXSLT stylesheet using javascript embedded in an HTML form.
I am wanting to filter my table data (multiple XML elements data that is being displayed as an HTML table in an area of the HTML form). If i had dvd title and price elements what would be an XPATH expression including predicate to let me display all the DVD title and price information (both elements) in a table showing only those with price > 2.00? At the moment I am having a lot of problems with regards to handling predicates to filter my table data and showing all the rows data for the 2 elements. I have an xpath expression
that lets me filter and show ONLY one of the elements but NOT the two. I would like to know how to
show 2 elements in a row (elements at the same level in the DOM) where one is filtering the other?

Grateful for any help.

I have update with the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<dvd>
<title>Gone with the wind</title><price>2.00</price>
</dvd>
<dvd>
<title>Independence Day</title><price>3.00</price>
</award>
</catalog>
```

As mentioned above I would like to have output in my HTML table the title AND price
output where the row(s) output is  those that satisfy price > 2.00

The content of the XML is simplified and there would be much more DVD elements
in it. I am passing XPATH expressions as strings into the XSLT template
in the for each and the value of select parts of the XSLT stylesheet.

The XSLT snippet is below. In javascript I am replacing the "*" in for each with
XPATH expression string "price[.>2.00]" which shows the price > 2.00. I want to be able to show
the title as well for that price as a row in my HTML table

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <tr>    
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
     <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Do you have some code examples explaining the question better?

Comment: You forgot to provide the source XML document (complete but minimal, please) and for this document you must specify which exactly nodes you want to be selected. Please, *edit* the question and provide this missing, important information.

Comment: daveb, Good you included the important information. One last thing is that it is good to provide both the XML document and the XSLT code (the latter is OK) in a well-indented, readable form. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/dvd[number(price) > 2.0]"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dvd">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/dvd[price > 2]
```

This selects any element named `dvd` that is a child of the top element of the XML document and that has at least one `price` child, whose string value converted to a number is greater than 2.